# errored: base fee exceeds gas limit

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

the default value for uint variable is 10
now on function call, I want to change this value to 0

steps to reproduce:

1. copy the following code to remix:

   ```
   contract test {
       uint128 public aPos=10;
       function updateQuota( uint128  _Quota){
           aPos = _Quota;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the environment as a web3 provider (configure local ganache server with remix ID)
3. Deploy contract.
4. Call `updateQuota` function with parameter as 0
5. Shows error as

> "transact to test.updateQuota errored: base fee exceeds gas limit "

.

Question: how to assign zero value to uint variable when we work with the web3 provider (local ganache server)

Comment: This (annoying) problem has also been reported on GitHub (web3.js if I remember correctly).

Comment: Surprisingly i'm facing exact same issue when following Pet Shop tutorial from Truffle. Have you managed to fix this? Long shot, but remember how?

Answer (score 2):

You most probably have assinged too little gas to the transaction. The Solidity code is fine (works as-expected with injected JS VM). 
Try using `gasPrice: 8000000000` and `gas: 4700000`, that should run fine on ganache.

Comment: i changes with this gas price and gas limit but still not working..

Comment: What values do you have for price + and block gas limit on the ganache gui? (i think the defaults are "6721975" for the maximum block gas and 20000000000 for the price)